# A Question about consecutive integers?

Tags: number-theory

Assume you have list of consecutive integers of length n, and such that each terms have at least one integer square factor. Then a couple of questions might be asked and i don't know if these has been asked by someone else before. Note, (8, 9) is the smallest length 2 such list and (48, 49, 50) is the smallest length 3 such  list. First what could be the bound for the maximum length of such list if it is bounded. Second there are many examples of length 2 lists, is it also bounded if not can we construct a family of solutions. Third what is the maximal length of the list that contains infinitely many solutions. References related with these kinds of problems would be nice.

Comment: I think you would find the Chinese Remainder Theorem very useful for this type of problem. Migrating this to M.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OEIS A045882](https://oeis.org/A045882) lists the smallest member of runs up to $18$ numbers.  There are infinitely many solutions, with length unbounded.  The [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) guarantees this.  For the run $48,49,50$ with squares $2^2,7^2,5^2$ the least common multiple of the squares is $4900$, so there is another run $4948,4949,4950$ with the same squares.  Given any list of primes (or other coprime numbers) you can find a list using CRT in any order you want.  If the primes are $p_1,p_2,p_3\dots p_n$, the smallest number $N$ of a chain of length $n$ will satisfy $N \equiv 0 \pmod {p_1^2}, N \equiv -1 \pmod {p_2^2}, N \equiv -2 \pmod {p_3^2}\dots N \equiv -n+1 \pmod {p_n^2}$

Comment: Though the question was about square factors, it might be worth noting that the same proof would work if you wanted cubes or higher powers as factors.

Comment: Wow, Thanks very much, nice solution i have never seen such an application of CRT